# Using grails - WSClient SSL errors "SSL peer shut down incorrectly "

Tags: web-services, grails, ssl, groovy

Trying to access a .NET web service (asmx) using grails.

I can successfully get the xml I am expecting using non-ssl. When I try to use ssl, I get errors when I actually make the webservice call.

Code and errors below:

```
def wsdlURL = "https://webservice(WSDL)"
def proxy = new WSClient(wsdlURL, this.class.classLoader)
proxy.initialize()

def outputData = proxy.WebServiceCall() <-- error here
```

Top of the errors:

```
java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly 

at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:462)

at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)

at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)

at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)

at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)

at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1934)

at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1889)

at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)

at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)

at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:96)
```